# Reseting touch takes too long in update

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, updates

Right now I have sprites moving across the screen, when you touch one you're "shooting" it. To see if any of the "enemies" have been "shot" I'm using `CGRectContainPoint` which works fine until I want it to take more that one hit to remove an enemy. This is the step up:

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {   

    _shot = bullet.position;
    BOOL enemyHit = FALSE;
    NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
        CGRect targetRect = target.boundingBox;

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(targetRect, _shot)) {
            enemyHit = TRUE;
            Enemy *enemy = (Enemy *)target;
            enemy.hp--;
            if (enemy.hp <= 0) {

                [targetsToDelete addObject:target];
            }
            break;          
        }                       
    }

    for (CCSprite *target in targetsToDelete) {
        [_targets removeObject:target];
        [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];                                  
    }

    [targetsToDelete release];

}
```

The problem I'm having is that it updates faster than it resets the touch location. So that in the time of one touch it will have brought the enemy health to -2 after starting at 3. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I really just don't have a way of setting a CGPoint where the touch is and then reseting it off screen after one iteration of the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to do your touch intersection test each time the user starts or completes a single touch, rather than continuously in your update loop, since you want the life of any touched sprite to decrement by exactly one after each touch.

You can do so by implementing either ccTouchesBegan or ccTouchesEnded (the choice depending on the tapping behavior you want):

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    _shot = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    _shot = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:_shot];

   // move your entire sprite intersection logic here
}
```